# Getting NetworkInfo from specific NetworkInterface

Tags: android

If I do enumeration on NetworkInterfaces to find a specific one called "swlan0" as like

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> it_ni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while (it_ni.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface ni = it_ni.nextElement();
    if (ni.getName() == "swlan0") {
        NetworkInfo ......  <----
    }
    Log.d(TAG, ni.getName().toString());
}
```

how I can get a NetworkInfo instance from that interface once found by name?.... Thanks to all! Cheers!

Comment: Not an answer, but you can simplify your code with NetworkInterface.getByName("swlan0") and not having to loop yourself.

Comment: Also, NetworkInfo is deprecated, you should probably find another way to do what you want.